# flexslider wont work unless window resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have a strange issue with flexslider but I also had the issue with bxslider, When I load the page flexslider will not work but if I resize the window it then works, I have added removed css/js but still the issue is there. You can see the issue here on my test server http://www.webcontrolcentre.co.uk/sitetest

if you navigate down to 'section four' you will see a link called 'view showcases' the slider is within that section.

Comment: load your js scripts in different order, your own script with document.ready as last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to reproduce without editable example, but FlexSlider usually has trouble initializing on hidden elements.

Does it work when you don't hide the .showcase?

You can try re-initializing the flexslider after clicking on the "show-btn"-toggle.

Comment: Yes if i remove/hide the .showcase the slider works, how would I re-initialize the slider?

Comment: You can try $('.flexslider').flexslider();

Comment: Or just use the code that you used to initialize it initially and put it into the function that happens on click on the toggler.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/skrollr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/skrollr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```